# Change Browser tab color on mobile

Tags: browser

As shown on the screenshot, brooklinen.com has this nice blue color on my mobile chrome tab as compared to the usual white/grey color.

I'm not sure what's the term of this effect would someone be able to advise what's the term for this and also how to implement it on a Wordpress/Woocommerce site?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QERj.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching the color of the address bar to your WordPress site gives it a native app-like feel. This improves user experience, which ultimately boosts sales and conversions. However, please note that currently it only works for Google Chrome web browser on Android devices using Lollipop or newer versions. Simply add this code in your theme or child theme‘s header.php file just before the closing  tag.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff6600" />
```

The content field has the hex code for the color you want to use as the theme color.

Comment: Hello Maximuf! Thank you for your reply :). I see the updated change in my browser now. Cheers!